# Conditions required for Taylor's theorem for multivariate functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

It's easy to find proofs for the following version of the Taylor's theorem for multivariate functions: Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $\mathbf a\in\mathbb R^n$ and $f:U\to\mathbb R^m$ a $C^k$ function. Then
$$f(\mathbf a+\mathbf h)=\sum^k_{i=0}{1\over i!}D^if(\mathbf a)\mathbf h^i+o(\|\mathbf h\|^k)$$
where $\mathbf h^i=(\mathbf h,\cdots,\mathbf h)\in(\mathbb R^n)^i$. For example, see

http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/taylor.pdf

I remember a long time ago I saw on the internet a proof of this theorem only assuming $f$ is $k$-times differentiable, not assuming it to be $C^k$. I didn't really pay much attention to the proof back then. Now I am again thinking about this question, but I failed to find anywhere this version of Taylor's theorem with the weaker condition despite considerable effort. And I could not prove it or disprove it myself. So I wonder does the above hold under this weaker condition? Could anyone point me to any literature on the subject? It seems plausible that it might be true, since we know that the $k=1$ case is true by definition of being differentiable, and moreover the $n=m=1$ case is also true by the one-dimensional Taylor's theorem. And if this is true, does it also hold if $f$ is just $k$-times differentiable at $\mathbf a$, instead of on the whole of $U$?